# Averaging different length vectors with same domain range in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the one shown in the code.

What I am guaranteed is that the "(var)x" (domain) of the variable is always between 0 and 1. The "(var)y" (co-domain) can vary but is also bounded, but within a larger range.

I am trying to get an average over the "(var)x" but over the different variables.

I would like some kind of selective averaging, not sure how to do this in R.

```
ax=c(0.11,0.22,0.33,0.44,0.55,0.68,0.89)
ay=c(0.2,0.4,0.5,0.42,0.5,0.43,0.6)

bx=c(0.14,0.23,0.46,0.51,0.78,0.91)
by=c(0.1,0.2,0.52,0.46,0.4,0.41)

qx=c(0.12,0.27,0.36,0.48,0.51,0.76,0.79,0.97)
qy=c(0.03,0.2,0.52,0.4,0.45,0.48,0.61,0.9)

a<-list(ax,ay)
b<-list(bx,by)
q<-list(qx,qy)
```

What I would like to have something like

```
avgd_x = c(0.12,0.27,0.36,0.48,0.51,0.76,0.79,0.97)
```

and

`avgd_y` would have contents that would

find the value of `ay` and `by` at 0.12 and find the mean with `ay`, `by` and `qy`.

Similarly and so forth for all the values in the vector with the largest number of elements.

How can I do this in R ?

P.S: This is a toy dataset, my dataset is spread over files and I am reading them with a custom function, but the raw data is available as shown in the code below.

Edit:

Some clarification:

`avgd_y` would have the length of the largest vector, for example, in the case above, `avgd_y` would be `(ay'+by'+qy)/3` where `ay'` and `by'` would be vectors which have `c(ay(qx(i)))` and `c(by(qx(i)))` for i from 1 to length of `qx`, `ay'` and `by'` would have values interpolated at data points of `qx`

Comment: how id avgd_y in the example above calculated? It look like its the same as qx

Comment: Please see updated question.